# Read BLOB object into pandas as CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, mariadb, blob

I have a mariaDB database that contains csvs in the form of BLOB objects. I wanted to read these into pandas, but it appears that the csv is stored as a text file in it's own cell, like this:

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| csv1 | col1, col2, ... |
| csv2 | col1, col2, ... |

How can I specifically read the cells in the data column as their own csvs into a pandas dataframe.

This is what I have tried:

```
raw = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
cell_as_string = raw.to_string(index=False)
converted_string = StringIO(cell_as_string)
rawdf = pd.read_csv(converted_string, sep = ',')
rawdf
```

However, rawdf is just the string with spaces, not a dataframe.

Here is a screenshot of what the query returns:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I ... read the cells ... into a pandas dataframe

Why is this even interesting?
It appears you already have the answer.
You are able to SELECT each item,
open a file for write, transfer the data,
and then ask [.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for a DataFrame.

But perhaps the requirement was to avoid spurious disk I/O.
Ok. The read_csv function accepts a file-like input,
and several libraries [offer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) such data objects.

If the original question
was [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would include
code that started like this:

```
from io import BytesIO, StringIO

default = "n,square\n2,4\n3,9"
blob = do_query() or default.encode("utf-8")
assert isinstance(blob, bytes)
```

Then with a binary BLOB in hand it's just a matter of:

```
f = StringIO(blob.decode("utf-8"))
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print(df.set_index("n"))
```

Sticking with bytes we might prefer the equivalent:

```
f = BytesIO(blob)
df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: Tried this already, made an edit

Comment: You told us the DB table values were CSVs. But now you're telling us that the text returned by the DB is not a CSV, it's not an acceptable input to `.read_csv`?!? I could try to read your mind. Or you could tell me what is happening. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what the first row of the DB table looks like. Also, if you read what I said, I said that after running pd.read_csv, we get a string with spaces, not before. The original DB table values were csvs.

Comment: I don't know the meaning of your screenshot. Apparently it corresponds to one of your defined variables, but it's unclear which one. It is clear that it describes bytes rather than unicode code points such as ASCII characters. Are you _sure_ that `cell_as_string` is actually a `str`, and not `bytes` ? Are you sure that the elided portion of that screenshot corresponds to newline delimited text lines with the identical number of comma-delimited fields as the (truncated) column headers your screenshot depicts? I recommend simplifying to a two-column dataframe, for debugging.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)